# Determine what is locking a USB device in Alpine (Home Assistant)

Tags: raspberry-pi, alpine-linux, usb-device

I'm running Home Assistant (standard RPi install) on a Raspberry Pi 4 GB with an AEOTEC Z-Stick Gen5. It's attached to a USB hub since the system won't use it otherwise. "Something" has grabbed ahold of the serial port so it's locked and the Z-Wave JS UI is unable to use it.

I get these messages but can't figure out what has it locked.

```
2023-01-28 19:47:14.536 INFO Z-WAVE: Connecting to /dev/ttyAMA0
2023-01-29T03:47:14.538Z DRIVER version 10.4.0
2023-01-29T03:47:14.539Z DRIVER
2023-01-29T03:47:14.539Z DRIVER starting driver...
2023-01-29T03:47:14.542Z DRIVER opening serial port /dev/ttyAMA0
2023-01-29T03:47:23.550Z DRIVER Failed to open the serial port: Error Resource temporarily unavailable Cannot lock port
```

I've looked at the "lsof" output, but I see no mention of the device which is /dev/ttyAMA0. Instead I get a list of **93 processes** which include:

```
1   /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-svscan    0   /dev/null
1   /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-svscan    1   pipe:[19812]
1   /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-svscan    2   pipe:[19813]
1   /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-svscan    3   /run/service/.s6-svscan/lock
1   /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-svscan    5   /run/service/.s6-svscan/control
1   /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-svscan    6   /run/service/.s6-svscan/control
1   /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-svscan    7   anon_inode:[signalfd]
15  /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-supervise 0   /dev/null
15  /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-supervise 1   pipe:[19812]
15  /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-supervise 2   pipe:[19813]
15  /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-supervise 3   /run/service/s6-linux-init-shutdownd/supervise/lock
15  /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-supervise 4   /run/service/s6-linux-init-shutdownd/supervise/control
15  /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-supervise 5   /run/service/s6-linux-init-shutdownd/supervise/control
15  /package/admin/s6-2.11.1.2/command/s6-supervise 6   anon_inode:[signalfd]
18  /package/admin/s6-linux-init-1.0.8.0/command/s6-linux-init-shutdownd    0   /dev/null
18  /package/admin/s6-linux-init-1.0.8.0/command/s6-linux-init-shutdownd    1   pipe:[19812]
18  /package/admin/s6-linux-init-1.0.8.0/command/s6-linux-init-shutdownd    2   pipe:[19813]
18  /package/admin/s6-linux-init-1.0.8.0/command/s6-linux-init-shutdownd    3   /run/service/s6-linux-init-shutdownd/fifo
.
.
.
```

This make absolutely no sense to me. Even worse 'fuser' returns nothing!

How can I determine what process is actually locking the device/serial port?

Comment: Does `sudo fuser /dev/ttyAMA0` show anything?

Comment: Thanks. I updated my post to include that 'fuser' returns nothing, and part of the huge listing from 'lsof /dev/AMA0'. I think I need to add some "real" linux commands with some teeth. Just not sure how to do that with Alpine linux.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the RP ecosystem to be of much help.  Anything useful at https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/z-wave/controllers/#aeotec-z-stick?  You might want to search and/or post a question to https://community.home-assistant.io/.

Comment: Thanks. I've been digging around on the Home Assistant site, the Discord for Home Assistant , here on Unix&Linux, and basically Googling everywhere. No one can seem to answer the question so I'm giving up and blowing the whole thing away. I've wasted days trying to figure this out. I'm done with it. But thank you for your suggestion.